# Science fiction novel involving starfighters called 'Loki,' which could jam everything around them

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space, military-sf

I'm trying to track down a military science fiction novel where Earth is in a losing war with an alien race.

I distinctly remember the human faction using starfighters called 'Loki,' which could jam everything around them. The protagonist also flees in the end on one ship after humans lose a major battle.

It was probably published in the early 2000s, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Ragnarok](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Ragnarok/a8Z0CwAAQBAJ?hl=en) by Patrick A. Vanner.

[image: Ragnarok]

> Humanity is locked in a war of survival with the Xan-Sskarn, an alien race that refuses to acknowledge the rights of "weaker" creatures to live. It is a war that will not end with a peace treaty, but only the complete subjugation of one species to the other. And right now, the alien side is winning.

The protagonist is Alex McLaughlin.

There's a description of the Loki fighters when *Alan Lewis* asks *Tracy Clark* about them:

> "Have you ever heard of Lokis?"
>
> "Yeah, we touched on them briefly at Intel school. Didn't go into too much depth, though. They're some kind of EW ship, right?"
>
> "Sort of, though they are more than a space-based Electronic Warfare platform. Anyway, Loki pilots are always referred to as Dead Jokers."
>
> Tracy watched Alan digest this information, waiting for the inevitable follow-up questions.

You can read the first chapter [on the Baen web site](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/1439133840/1439133840.htm) (though that doesn't mention the *Loki* fighters).

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, that is the book I was looking for.